# Render Looks Brighter Than Preview Camera (FFmpeg Desaturation)

Tags: rendering, animation, edit-mode, eevee-render-engine

Before switching from filmic to standard worked, but now it doesn't anymore.

Left side is render preview and right side is the final render. Final render is way lighter and even removing everything except my HDRI light, it still shows in render different than in preview

Here's project file https://pasteall.org/blend/0ba76b41e5de46fe8b2cd3349af811ec

[image]

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/cace256febd94147b07086551f263fd7

Comment: I can't upload it because it becomes 88mb

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/7a259cee5e6142f0ab8964a1f6f1f029 try this without hdri. Still shows different colors

Comment: use another platform. See my render on the left, I can't see any difference with the preview on the right: https://zupimages.net/up/22/13/2xmf.jpg ... so I'm not sure what's happening for you, it may have nothing to do with the HDRI. What is the image you're showing in your question, a screenshot? Or have you opened the render with a software? In that case it may be a problem of format interpretation?

Comment: I'm referring to the render preview and the actual animation that gets saved to quicktime player. The left image is the render preview from pressing F12 and the right is the video from quicktime player that resulted from the finished render

Comment: oh ok so it looks like it's loosing its color when you render in Ffmepg4

Comment: but if I open the movie in Blender itself it looks fine with no desaturation, maybe it's due to your movie app? see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180270/desaturated-video-after-rendering .. is the image on the right a screenshot from your video app?

Comment: yes the lighter right image is the actual video, so it makes it difficult to know what color to use in blender if my video app isn't receiving the colors properly.

Comment: Yes I can see the problem as well, with whatever video app I use

Comment: so would rendering it as images then convert to video solve this or there's no solution using eevee?

Comment: it looks the same if you render as images then export as ffmpeg4, I don't know where it comes from and how to solve it, I hope somenone will know

Comment: I wonder if this thread is not related to the same problem? https://developer.blender.org/T60947

Comment: ok question asked here on blenderartists: https://blenderartists.org/t/ffmpeg-desaturation/1370535

Comment: ah so seems like a problem that hasn't been solved for a few years now... :/ so I guess I just need to get a faster comp to render cycles?

Comment: oh ok I didn't know it was working with Cycles, good to know

Comment: ok so according to lucas.coutin: "You have red values higher than 1, you need to export an EXR image sequence to store those. Any kind of movie file will clamp it." I let you check that  ;) https://blenderartists.org/t/ffmpeg-desaturation/1370535